# drop columns below a certain value count of a specific character

Tags: python, pandas, apply

Some columns of dataframe, df, have elements equal to "?" character. The df has 2000 rows. I want to drop the columns where more than 1800 elements are equal to "?".

I think I need to use the apply method to figure out which columns need to be dropped and then use drop method to drop them but I can't figure out how.

```
df.drop(df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()["?"]>1800 ,axis=0))
```

but obviously it doesn't work. The above line is not the first thing I tried. I've tried many other things as well but they all give me different errors. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not necessarily have to use `apply` method and `value_counts`; Checking equality and sum can do the same thing here and would potentially be more efficient:

```
df.eq("?").sum()
```

gives the amount of `?` in each column:

```
df.eq("?").sum().gt(1800)
```

gives a boolean series where if the column has more than 1800 question marks, it's marked as True, and this can be further used to subset the data frame with `loc`; So put together:

```
df.loc[:,~df.eq("?").sum().gt(1800)]
```

---

To use `drop` method, you need to make sure what you are passing in are labels or list of column names instead of a boolean series and also to drop columns, you need to specify axis parameter to be 1, so to make your original answer work:

```
df.drop(df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()["?"]>1800)[lambda x: x].index, axis=1)
#                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
# here use a lambda filter to extract column names that need to be dropped
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The column types are object, int64 and float64. With your loc solution, I get: 

TypeError: Could not compare ['?'] with block values


and with your drop solution, I get: 

KeyError: ('?', 'occurred at index communityname') 

where communityname is one of the columns. Could it be that I need to convert the types before using your solution? I think ?s are in both object and numeric columns.

Comment: In case you have mixed data type, you could use `select_dtypes` to select object types firstly and then compare with question mark and make the column names to be dropped: `df.drop(df.select_dtypes([object]).eq("?").sum().gt(1800)[lambda x: x].index, axis=1)`.

Comment: Thank you! Your drop method now works although it's a bit hard for me to understand the second lambda.index part; I need to think about it... However, just out of curiosity, once I try using your loc method as: df.loc[:,~df.select_dtypes([object]).eq("?").sum().gt(1800)] I get: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
Any idea how I can get the loc work?

Comment: To get the `loc` method work for mixed type, you need to make sure the boolean series has the same length as the number of columns, since `select_dtypes` dropped numeric columns, the length doesn't equal anymore, thus *unalignable*. You could use `apply` method with `loc` as this: `df.loc[:,df.apply(lambda col: col.dtype != object or col.eq("?").sum() <= 1800)]`